# React.js Passing Functions to Components: Bind vs no-Binds

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "Bob";
    this.handleClickTwo = this.handleClickOne.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClickOne() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
  
  handleClickThree = () => alert(this.name);
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickOne }> Click One </button>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickTwo }> Click Two </button>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickThree }> Click Three </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

I'm trying to understand React.js more, and I wanted to test out some things. Clicking buttons with the label "Click Two" and "Click Three" work as intended meaning it shows an alert for the name "Bob".

But when I click the button labelled "Click One", it gives me an error saying that 'name' is an undefined property.

Am I misunderstanding React.js or JS in general? Does the 'this' in handleClickOne() refer to the function itself and not what's in the constructor? And if so, why does handeClickTwo work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does the "this" keyword work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3127429/how-does-the-this-keyword-work)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

functions are not bound by default in javascript. You didn't bind `handleClickOne`, so you can't call `this.handleClickOne`

`handleClickTwo` is bound in your code in the constructor, using `this.handleClickTwo = this.handleClickOne.bind(this)`.

`handleClickThree` uses [public class fields syntax](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-class-properties) to correctly bind the callback, so it works as well.

To bind `handleClickOne`, you must use `this.handleClickOne = this.handleClickOne.bind(this)` to bind it in the constructor.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.name = "Bob";
    this.handleClickOne = this.handleClickOne.bind(this);
    this.handleClickTwo = this.handleClickOne.bind(this);
  }
  
  handleClickOne() {
    alert(this.name);
  }
  
  handleClickThree = () => alert(this.name);
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickOne }> Click One </button>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickTwo }> Click Two </button>
        <button onClick={ this.handleClickThree }> Click Three </button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```